# lstlisting only shows single line number on top

Tags: listings, babel

I am using lstlisting as part of a large document, and I wish to present line numbers. I am using the following code:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++, numbers=left, frame=single, escapechar=@]
int a = 1; // first line @\label{demo:first_line}@
int b = 2; // second line @\label{demo:second_line}@
int c = 3; // third line @\label{demo:third_line}@
\end{lstlisting}
a appears in line \ref{demo:first_line}.
b appears in line \ref{demo:second_line}.
c appears in line \ref{demo:third_line}.
```

However, only a single number appears on the top left corner (changing the "numbers" flag to "right" will move it to the top right corner). 
Also, the frame appears to be broken and references to line numbers are all 0.
See picture:

[image]

I copied the same code to a clean document, and everything worked fine:

[image]

**EDIT:**
The following code reproduces the problem:

custom.cls:

```
\def\filename{custom}
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage[hebrew,english]{babel}
\endinput
```

main.tex:

```
\documentclass{custom}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++, numbers=left, frame=single, escapechar=@]
int a = 1; // first line @\label{demo:first_line}@
int b = 2; // second line @\label{demo:second_line}@
int c = 3; // third line @\label{demo:third_line}@
\end{lstlisting}
a appears in line \ref{demo:first_line}.
b appears in line \ref{demo:second_line}.
c appears in line \ref{demo:third_line}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks for the useful link about (MWEs). While minimizing, I already found the problem.

Comment: Then, what was the problem?

Comment: I edited the original question to include the solution as well.
A "\RequirePackage[hebrew,english]{babel}" command inside the cls was the source of the problem. I did not actually need that package in the document, so I simply removed it.

Comment: We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Comment: Thanks. I edited again to include code reproducing the problem in the question, and moved the answer to a post of its own.

Answer (score 2):

The "\RequirePackage[hebrew,english]{babel}" command inside the cls file is the source of the problem. Removing it resolves the problem.

More specifically, the problem is with "hebrew".
Relacing the command with
"\RequirePackage[english]{babel}" also resolved the problem.